# There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos2.2.1' LinkedIn-iPhone

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, linkedin-api

I download a sample project of linkedin integration with iPhone Application 
http://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

I run the demo project

but giving error

```
error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos2.2.1'
```

I am using XCode Version 3.2.4

I also try to change the Base SDK and iOS Develoment Target to 3.2/4.0/4.1, but same error occur.

**-Amit Battan**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is caused by the SDK setting in the dependent sub-project OAuthLib library project not being updated for the latest SDK.

Updated project files are available on the fork at git://github.com/Smartovation/LinkedIn-iPhone.git

Comment: I have try the code you suggested , in Demo after login it redirect to linkedin website in UIWebView .. not comeback to iphone app